# Possibility of SQL query to return a result set that has more than one column with the same name

Tags: java, sql, oracle, resultset

From oracle doc
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/resultset.html

> In some cases, it is possible for an SQL query to return a result set
>   that has more than one column with the same name. If a column name is
>   used as the parameter to a getXXX method, getXXX will return the value
>   of the first matching column name.

Anybody knows about "some cases"?

Comment: Join two tables having a common column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest case is

```
select 1 as A, 2 as A from dual
```

much the same way someone may (unwillingly) create equal aliases in a complex query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a common example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.table1Id = table2.table1Id;
```

Here you know `table1` and `table2` have a column named `table1Id`, and it is guaranteed to have the same value.  However if you have a self-join:

```
SELECT * FROM employee e JOIN employee m ON e.manager_id = m.id;
```

Now you have a problem and, probably, your result set will not make as much sense.

Comment: The JOIN USING query is supposed to return only one table1Id column.

Comment: Thanks!  I have corrected the example.  However it is worth noting that at least on PostgreSQL, USING() does not immediately remove the duplicate columns so you cannot have USING() on the same column name for two different joins (which was why I thought it did not).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two tables defined as

- *Authors*: AuthorId, FirstName, LastName, Title...
- *Books*: BookId, Title, ISBN, AuthorId...

where one would want to list books with author information using the following SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM Books
JOIN Authors USING (AuthorId)
```

Now you have two unrelated `title` columns in the `ResultSet`, one being the title of the book and one being the (e.g. academic) title of the author.